# Cannot receive WooCommerce emails / WP emails, Linux mail (ssh) works

Tags: email, woocommerce

Issue : WooCommerce emails are not received.

**What does work :**

1) with ssh connexion to server, if I use mail Linux command, its works.

2) With WP, Check Email plugin works as well.

3) A user changed his password, I received the email notification, as others WP emails notifications : new user created, and others ...

**What does not work :**

When I bought something (as a buyer), I have the PayPal email, but any WC email.
Someone else did the same test, same issue.

When I send (as admin) manually, an email to a customer (myself) with WC, it does not work as well.

I think I set up correctly emails with WC : check box => activate notification.
I did not change the look of emails.

Either HTML or text emails does not work.

At the moment, I would not like to use any SMTP plugin, as my server can send emails.

I don't know where to look for about this issue ?

Might PayPal forbid WC to send emails ?

Thank you for your help !

Nils

Answer (score 0):

I just had to set up reverse DNS with domain name to make it works.